# php reading only first line of list

Tags: php

I am new at php and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to list all the records from a txt file. However, my code is only displaying the first line. How can I get the code to display all the records from the file?

```
$count = 0;
$soldOut = 0;
$eventFile = fopen("performances.txt", "r");
$event = fgets($eventFile);

while ( feof($eventFile));
{
    list ($dateEvent, $performer, $ticketprice, $status) = explode(":", $event);
    if($status == "Yes")
    {
        $status =  "Tickets are still available";
        $count = $status +1;
    }
    else
    {
        $status =  "***SOLD OUT***";
        $soldOut = $status +1;
    }

    print("<tr><td>$dateEvent </td>");
    print("<td>$performer </td>");
    print("<td>$ticketprice </td>");
    print("<td>$status</td></tr>");
    $event = fgets($eventFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the [docs](http://php.net/feof), you'll notice that your loop should be:

```
while( !feof($eventFile)) {
    $event = fgets($eventFile); // THIS is where you get the current line
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for downvote? Generally I comment before clicking the Downvote button...

Answer (score 0):

you can read file this way. You can find more on this https://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("performances.txt",FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); //read the file
$convert = explode(":", $data); //create array separate by new line

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    echo $convert[$i].', '; //write value by index
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping as instructed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Basically, keep looping until fgets nolonger returns anything, and then check if pointer matches with end of file.
I also suggest you take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php
the comments make a case for performance gains.

```
$count = $soldOut = 0;
$eventFile = fopen("performances.txt", "r");
if ($eventFile) {
    # Keep reading as long as fgets returns content
    while ( ($event = fgets($eventFile)) !== false ) {
        list ($dateEvent, $performer, $ticketprice, $status) = explode(":", $event);
        if($status == "Yes") {
            $status =  "Tickets are still available";
            ++$count; # increase count with one
        } else {
            $status =  "***SOLD OUT***";
            ++$soldOut; # increase soldout with one
        }

        echo '<tr>',
            '<td>',$dateEvent,'</td>',
            '<td>',$performer,'</td>',
            '<td>',$ticketprice,'</td>',
            '<td>',$status,'</td>',
        '</tr>';
    }
    # something went wrong
    if (!feof($eventFile)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    # remember to close them files
    fclose($eventFile);
} else {
    # failed to open
}
```